# PyCharm Nagivate to Function

Tags: python, pycharm

In Sublime I can do ctrl+r to bring up a list of methods/functions and classes in the current file and then navigate directly to that function. Which has been unbelievably handy in browsing and navigating unfamiliar files. In PyCharm I am having a hard time finding what that equivalent option is.

I can't find anything in the key mapping that looks similar and searching the python documentation keeps directing me to the 'Navigating to class, file or symbol' which generally is unhelpful as it finds everything outside the open file first, can't list what's in the file, and most notably - can't find single functions. I'm sure it's something stupid, but google searches haven't been helpful.

(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/structure-tool-window-file-structure-popup.html

Comment: `ctrl+b` I think is what you want :) it will take you to the definition if you are on a use of it ... otherwise it will show you all uses of it if you are on the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **CTRL + F12**

It would give you the file structure

Comment: `ctrl+b` i think is what he wants

Comment: No, ctrl+F12 is exactly what I'm looking for. As @wyatt points out, it's listed under the Tool Windows section of the pycharm reference. Not 'Navigating the Source Code' as I was expecting and searching through. (And has a title I'd never think to search for, I mean, I used 'navigate' in the title of this question, not 'structure').